# Best git config for local kernel patch maintenance

Tags: git, linux-kernel, gitlab

I'm not a git expert.
Scenario: local linux running gitlab git server.

I need to make several patches to a linux kernel. So i want one git to hold the entire tree.
However, i would prefer that either the local git will only hold the patches and or new files. Or. To the least, will hold a copy of it but will be aware where it pulls from if i want to grab baseline updates.

All this - while the actual dev machine that will clone from my local git server machine will receive an entire copy of the tree.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Note: I might need to apply these features to several different kernels. So I'd prefer storing just the changes and so I could easily switch baselines.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know whether to mark this "too broad" or "unclear", but what you're asking for here is a general tutorial on how to use git, while expressing preferences for how it should work without any concrete examples of how those differ from the behavior you're seeing. So it's hard to compose a response with any focus on anything.

Answer (score 0):

A local Git will hold:

- the full history of the repo (unless you do a shallow clone)
- a checked out working tree with all files.

If you want to test between different patches, you can:

- clone once
- checkout multiple branches in different folders ([see `git worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309))

That way, you can easily switch between different patch you want to test.